# Does debezium 2.4 need/support antlr runtime 3 or 4?

Tags: debezium, debezium-engine

Does debezium 2.4 need/support antlr runtime 3 or 4?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

OR

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

We are trying to figure out which dependency to include in our pom.xml.

Update:
Looks like we shouldn't include any antlr dependency in our pom.xml at all. The debezium connector will automatically include the dependency that it needs.

```
+- io.debezium:debezium-connector-mysql:jar:2.4.0.Final:compile
|  +- io.debezium:debezium-storage-kafka:jar:2.4.0.Final:compile
|  +- io.debezium:debezium-storage-file:jar:2.4.0.Final:compile
|  +- io.debezium:debezium-ddl-parser:jar:2.4.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.10.1:compile
```